# Best Practice re User/Login Setup for SSRS on personal Development laptop

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to learn a little SSRS and using my own personal laptop to do so.  Now that I have built some simple reports which connect to an Azure SQL Database, I have taken the next step and deployed a new report to the Report Server which is on my laptop.   However, now I CANNOT access that report via the Report Server.

My problem is that I am facing multiple errors – some of them circular – as I try to do this.  Most of these errors are related to Security/Login/User issues (an area of personal unfamiliarity despite efforts at self-education).
Some background (Names & ids have obviously been changed to protect the clueless):

•   Laptop (My Development machine)

o   Running  SQL Server 2014

o   Windows 10

o   Name: LAPTOP-XXX

•   Windows Credentials

o   Account:  Hank Clueless (with a SPACE between the First & Last Name)

•   Databases

o   ReportServer (on LAPTOP-XXX)

o   DDX on Azure SQL Database

•   Users  (All Users are setup for SQL Server Authentication)

o   ReportServer

- Dbo
- hc
- guest
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA
- NT SERVICE\ReportServer
- Sys

o   DDX

- dbo
- hc
- abc (other users)
- guest
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA
- Sys

After some struggle, I have been able to deploy my first report to ReportServer.  However, when I want to access that report via a browser, my troubles begin.

1. Using a browser, I try to navigate to  _http://LAPTOP-XXX/ReportServer.  I am them prompted for User Name & Password to connect to LAPTOP-XXX.  The only Windows Account for my machine is Hank Clueless, so that is the only acceptable credential here.  Using ‘Hank Clueless’ – I AM able to connect, but I immediately get a Reporting Services Error message in the Browser:  The permissions granted to user 'LAPTOP-XXX\Hank Clueless' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
2. Hank Clueless is NOT a USER in the ReportServer database
3. The ReportServer USER dbo is associated with the LOGIN name 'LAPTOP-XXX\Hank Clueless'
4. I cannot add a NEW USER to ReportServer and associate that new user with 'LAPTOP-XXX\Hank Clueless' because I get an ERROR “That Login already has an account under a different user name’

Questions:

What is the best practice for setting up a Development ReportServer on a personal laptop?  Development Users?

How do I enhance the privileges for 'LAPTOP-XXX\Hank Clueless' so that I can see – and ultimately RUN – the new SSRS reports that I have deployed to my own machine?

Hank Clueless has NO login, user or access to the Azure SQL database (DDX).  I use SQL Server Authentication.  Do you have any guidance for the inevitable problems I am going to face passing credentials to DDX?

I welcome any guidance on this and thank you in advance for reading this.

‘Hank Clueless’

Comment: I don't know the answer but I might be able to help you in the right direction. SSRS defaults access to BUILTIN\Users and BUILTIN\Administrators. I don't know how a personal computer handles those groups. If you want to try and insert a record for yourself in the dbo.Users it might be fun to try. You could just modify the BUILTIN\Administrators, change UserType to 0, username to your domain login (or I guess laptop_name\user) and give that a shot. *shrug* Could work.

Comment: Hi Lucky,  Thanks for the suggestion.  I looked promising when I went to users and saw the Windows User listed but with 0 as the UserType value.  I changed that to 1 but alas, it did not resolve the problem.  I wonder if the issue is with the permissions to the underlying dataset, so I am going to try a very simple report linked to an Access db ON my laptop and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to find an answer re the insufficient privileges.  This does not define any Best Practices, but the answer below does explain to resolve this issue and I am now able to access SSRS local ReportServer via browser.

Fortunately, after continued searching, I was able to find a great article on this problem:

http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/reportserver-permissions-granted-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied

I followed the directions and it worked. Thanks to that site and the author - Doug.